# A page above the current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My need is to find how to code a page, when I click on a text/link/photo/etc., to open a page over current one like is open a photo on Facebook.

What I really want to do, you find in link below and go on "Client area" and click one of that 3 photos. That is want I want to do.

https://www.wix.com/demone2/family-photographer

Comment: This is called a lightbox.

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the page in a div, set that div to `position: absolute;` and `top: 50px` and `right: 50px`, set it's display to none by default, and then use JS to trigger the display like so

```
document.getElementById("<your ID>").style.display = "block";
```

You can also make another div that has a gray background that is slightly transparent, set it's width and height to `100%`, and do the same thing with the display

Answer (score 0):

So, I think a lot after you guys says me about the lighbox. I make the style like lightbox: when click on something it open over current page. And in place of that slider I include a iframe with another page. That solved my need :)
Thanks for helping!